# Alternative to HTML standard for expressing static documents content

Tags: html, web-services

The content tends to be mixed with it's form when expressed as a HTML+CSS+JS document. Almost every modern website requires CSS and/or JavaScript to be readable. Most of them are not easy to parse automatically because they relay on web browser to render it. Sections of the document are defined using visual clues, colors and formatting. One can use HTML5 tags like `<article>` but those are not a part of any bigger structure as far as I know, and still can contain non-content elements.

Websites are basically *apps* or **clients**.

Is there any standard that can be used to serve content of a website that has a well defined schema? An API for websites that could be used to express content in the form that is easy to server, parse, store, cryptographically sign...

I'm aware of formats like XML and JSON but I have not managed to find any standardized way to express a blog post as a JSON document.

An example of what I have in mind:
This question can be fetched as an JSON document using [Stackexchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=32779895&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true). The result is machine readable and easy to parse but is in not standardized. It reflects details of Stackexchange specific data structures. Other QA website will have different API, with different structure and formats even though both have questions and answers.

Comment: CSS was meant to disconnect the content from its form actually, but I think I see what you mean. What I don't see is what you have in mind. How are you proposing to display the content, if not with a web browser (or depending on the file format, a word processor, pdf reader etc)? You always need a program to render anything! So I'm not sure what direction you're thinking in.

Comment: I'm searching for the pure content representation. But I get your point, that there is no point for it if there is no way to render it. I hope that there is some obscure standard somewhere.

Comment: MacOS has files like you're describing, with the pure data in the data fork and all the formatting info in the resource fork. So if you're interested only in the textual content, you only read the data fork. I have no idea how these things work though; my contact with Macs has only ever been as an end user, not a developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two important standards out there dealing with the semantic aspect of a web page, like the one you are looking for. Microdata and RDFa. With their aid, you can pick a certain open vocabulary to describe your data or create your own based on them.
With JSON-LD also, you can create a schema for JSON documents like the XML schema is for the XML documents.